# What's the difference between Promise.reject an error and Promise.reject object?

Tags: node.js, promise

I was reading some nodejs tutorial which talks about rejection in nodejs. They say that it's best practice to reject an error instead of a string or an plain text. Taking example of this code.

This is a example of rejecting a string

```
function cookMeat(chef){
    grillMeat(chef)
    .then(meat => {
        if(chef.isTired){
             return Promise.reject(chef.tiredReason);
         }
         return Promise.resolve(meat);
    })
}
function cookNoodle(cheif){
    boilNoodle(chef)
    .then(noodle => {
        if(chef.isTired){
             return Promise.reject(chef.tiredReason);
         }
         return Promise.resolve(noodle);
    })
}

function cook(){
    let chef
    prepareFood()
    .then(c => {
        chef = c;
        return true;
    })
    .then(() => cookMeat(chef))
    .then(() => cookNoodle(chef))
    .catch(err => {
         state: Fail,
         reason: error
     })
     .then(res => {
         state:Ready
     })
}
cook()
.then((res) => serveCustomer(res))
```

And this is a example of rejecting an error

```
function cookMeat(chef){
    grillMeat(chef)
    .then(meat => {
        if(chef.isTired){
             return Promise.reject(new Error(chef.tiredReason));
         }
         return Promise.resolve(meat);
    })
}
function cookNoodle(cheif){
    boilNoodle(chef)
    .then(noodle => {
        if(chef.isTired){
             return Promise.reject(new Error(chef.tiredReason));
         }
         return Promise.resolve(noodle);
    })
}

function cook(){
    let chef
    prepareFood()
    .then(c => {
        chef = c;
        return true;
    })
    .then(() => cookMeat(chef))
    .then(() => cookNoodle(chef))
    .catch(err => {
         state: Fail,
         reason: error.message
     })
     .then(res => {
         state:Ready
     })
}
cook()
.then((res) => serveCustomer(res))
```

Since I want to use reject to skip part of the promise chain. So I am wondering if there are any difference?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Answer (score 1):

wPromise rejections are similar to throwing exceptions / error objects.

There are two rules that apply to throwing exceptions that apply here too:

1. In javascript, it's better to throw an Error object. Among other things, you will get stack information. It's also what most people expect when using a javascript code base.
2. Don't use exceptions for flow-control

The second one is such a common advice, you can google it verbatim and learn more. You're using Promise rejections as flow control and this is a bad idea.

Your functions can be rewritten a bit though. This is even better:

```
function cookMeat(){
    grillMeat()
    .then(meat => {
        if(meat.isRaw){
             throw new Error(meat.rawReason);
        }
        return meat;
    });
}

function cookNoodle(){
    boilNoodle()
    .then(noodle => {
        if(noodle.isRaw){
            throw new Error(noodle.rawReason);
        }
        return noodle;
    })
}

function cook(){
    return prepareFood()
    .then(() => cookMeat())
    .then(() => cookNoodle())
    .catch(err => {
        state: Fail,
        reason: error.message
    })
    .then(res => {
        state:Ready
    })
}
cook()
.then((res) => talkWithCustomer(res))
```

I got rid of your `Promise.reject` and `Promise.resolve` statements, because they are unneccary from within a then() function. The advice to use them only really applies 'outside' of then() chains.

Comment: I agreed with you that use exception is a bad idea. If I want quit a promise chain early if some part went wrong other then rejection?. Is there a good way to do that? Say a people wants to cook  beef then fish then chicken then vegetable. But durning cooking chicken, the wok broke. Then he can't cook vegetable anymore. It turns out that he can still eat beef and fish at last. Saying if cooking each dish is async operation. Then at least beef and fish is returned. Is there a good flow to handle this logic?

Comment: Hi @burytheupsidedown those examples do sound like exceptions to me. They are real errors and they should interupt the flow.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that explanation.